# How do I force the save routine in ContentTools to save all regions regardless if they changed?

Tags: content-tools

I used the save routine from the [Getting Started](http://getcontenttools.com/getting-started) page and it works with my back end coding as long as I edit all regions on the page before saving. However if I don't edit a region it's data is not passed.

The js script on the page above has this:

```
// Check to see if there are any changes to save
regions = ev.detail().regions;
if (Object.keys(regions).length == 0) {
    return;
}
```

How would I save all the regions even if there aren't changes?

I know it's inefficient but that's how I need to do it right now.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that contenttools doesn't even send the region name if it hasn't been edited, so I can check for that in the back end. Problem solved.